# How does Ms. Marvel fly?

Tags: comics, marvel, powers

Using her original Kree-given powers, how did Ms. Marvel fly? Was this an ability that all Kree had, or was she manipulating gravity, or what? Or was it never explained past "she can fly"?

She still flies to this day, but I'm not sure if that is still due to the influence of the Kree (she's had a LOT of powersets).

Comment: It's not an answer, but here's some good info on her; http://marvel.wikia.com/Carol_Danvers_%28Earth-616%29 Given the list of abilities, I can see a number of ways that she could be accomplishing it, but with luck someone else will know the 'canon' answer.

Comment: She falls to the ground and misses, same as Superman.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

SFF.SE's own [Brett White caught up with Kelly Sue DeConnick at HeroesCon 2012](http://youtu.be/EFLvtIIZNHg). She's going to be authoring Ms Marvel as Captain Marvel and he asked her the question.  Her answer:

> When she originally flew, it was actually due to her costume.  It was not inherent in her being, it was in the costume.  In fact there's a panel you see sort of an x-ray of the costume, and she gets stripped of the costume and it gets given to someone else. ... The power of flight was in the costume originally.

The panel Kelly refers to is from Ms Marvel #2:

[image]

As you can see it explicitly explains her ability to fly.

Comment: Are those villains wearing top hats for heads? Also, why is she wearing shorts sized for 6 yr olds? Which superpower allows her to squeeze into those?

Comment: It was a simpler time back then...

Comment: I am glad that 1. someone watches our videos (StackHQ on YouTube!) and 2. someone put this on the site and is getting rep for it (I would rather accept someone ELSE'S answer and give them rep than answer my own question and be a rep hog). Yes!

Comment: @BrettWhite get someone to whip up an ad for it as part of the community ads.  I only got there from the blog, didn't realise there was more of them. :)

Comment: @dlanod Done! http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/a/2060/2383 Upvote if you wish!

Answer (score 14):

Ms. Marvel was originally Carol Danvers, just a regular human working at NASA where she happened to meet one Dr. Phillip Lawson (we know him as the Kree super hero called Captain Marvel).  A romance blossomed between them after he saves her life and after hearing of said romance, a Kree enemy (Yon-Rogg) kidnaps Carol to draw Captain Marvel into a trap.  During the fight, the Captain shields her from a powerful, and forbidden, Kree machine known as the Psyche-Magnitron.

The machine (essentially) pushes radiation through Captain Marvel into her, which effectively mixes her human DNA with that of the Kree.  The process was influenced by her wanting to be Marvel's equal, instead of the helpless girl he kept saving, as well as her dreams of flight and having super powers.  As a result, the encounter leaves her with her first set of abilities: super-strength, durability, enhanced fighting skills on par with the Kree Warriors, a 'danger' sense, and flight.  She adopted the name Ms. Marvel then.

Later she was in a battle with Rogue that left her powerless, eventually got herself kidnapped by more aliens (the Brood race this time), and their experimenting left her with much stronger powers than before.  She changed her name to Binary for some time, but she still retained a form of flight and eventually her original, albeit enhanced, powers came back to her, where after she returned to the Avengers.